# Food ingredients (in the EU) where it’s uncertain whether they are vegan or not

Tags: veganism, food, labeling, eu

In the European Union, what are the ingredients (as listed on the labels of packaged food products) where it’s **uncertain** whether they are vegan or non-vegan?

So I’m not asking about ingredients that are always/never vegan, but only about those where you would have to ask the producer to know.

Answer (score 4):

My answer comes from [this French source](https://doucefrugalite.com/2013/10/03/les-produits-non-vegan-a-eviter/). If you have an English one, feel free to add it in the comment.

- **Refined sugar**: some brand use bone powder to whiten and purify sugar.
- **Gelatin**: can be from pork or fruit.
- **Alcoholic beverages** (beer, wine, etc...): one of the step in creating an alcoholic beverage involves using [finings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finings) (either to improve clarity or adjust flavor or aroma). The fining can use gelatin, casein, albumen, or isinglass which aren't vegan. However, some fining use algae which is vegan.
- **Vitamin D in conditioned juices**: vitamin D can be from fish oil, animal gelatin, sheep wool fibers (all not vegan) or can be from synthesis (vegan).
- **Natural aroma of vanilla (or raspberry or strawberry)**: can be from mushroom or [beaver gland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castoreum) (castoreum). Note that "natural extract of vanilla" are always from vanilla.